# What package managers are supported on Microsoft hosted agents with CMake enabled?

Tags: azure-devops, dependency-management, azure-pipelines

[Here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/tasks/build/cmake?view=vsts), I can read that it is possible to setup a CMake build on a Microsoft hosted vsts agent. What C++ package managers (e.g. Conan) are supported for these agents?

It would be great if at least one of these package managers is supported: https://github.com/nlohmann/json#package-managers

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/package/overview?view=vsts), the hosted agent supports NuGet, npm, and Maven.

It looks like it might also support `pip`.
You could install `cget` using `pip` and then use `cget` to install your package. A bit of a roundabout way, but it might do what you need.

```
"C:\Program Files\Python36\Scripts\pip" install cget
cget install nlohmann/json
```

I don't have a way to test this right now, but I will try some real examples and edit tomorrow if I have time.

Since it is a CMake/Git project, you could also just clone the repository (or add it as a [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)) and build it every time. Since I often use libraries that aren't managed, I tend to take this route and leverage the caching that many CI platforms offer to keep my build times low. Sadly, it looks like VSTS hasn't gotten to this [yet](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/32044321-improve-hosted-build-agent-performance-with-build).